# MySQL: SELECT @var:=dummy FROM t1 JOIN @var

Tags: mysql, dynamic

Is it possible to select from a column as result of row?

I got a table with datetimes and need/want to select/join from a table storing business expenses in columns depending on the year which would be result of a select.

Since i need the values stored for each year i thought this table design would be best but maybe I am totally off...

Follwing a simple example table:

```
SELECT 
  @var:=DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,"%Y"), 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN @sp8:=someINT END as sp8,
  CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN @sp24:=someINT END as sp24,
  t2.sp8_@var,
  t2.sp24_@var
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.Loc=t2.Loc) WHERE 1;

t1                  t2
+--+----------+---+   +---+---------+--------+---------+
|id|datetime  |Loc|   +Loc+sp24_2017+sp8_2017+sp24_2018+
+--+----------+---+   +---+---------+--------+---------+
|1 |2017-03-01|DE |   +DE +24       +12      +24       +
|2 |2016-03-01|GB |   +GB +47       +23      +48       +
+--+----------+---+   +---+---------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question.   You have a query that returns a year, and you want to use that year in another query?

Comment: Question is: Is MySQL able to use value of selected row plus string as a column Name within the same query. Like define a variable Name as column Name to query dynamically.